# TomEE DataSource Resource gets "NoWait: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection, none available[5 in use]."

Tags: spring, tomcat, datasource, apache-tomee

I'm running TomEE 7.0.1 in Eclipse Neon.  I've defined a DataSource resource in the "tomee.xml" file.  The DataSource connects to an Oracle DB, and I'm getting the driver from my local Maven repo.

When TomEE starts up, I get the following error in the console:

```
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException: [main] NoWait: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection, none available[5 in use].
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:679)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:468)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:143)
at org.apache.tomee.jdbc.TomEEDataSourceCreator$TomEEConnectionPool.<init>(TomEEDataSourceCreator.java:221)
```

Here is my Resource definition:

```
<Resource id="global/foo/bar" type="DataSource" classpath="mvn:oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.3">
    JdbcDriver = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    MaxActive = 5
    MinIdle = 2
    MaxIdle = 2 
    MaxWait = 10000
    JdbcUrl = jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:1521:sus2
    UserName = <userid>
    Password = <password>
</Resource>
```

I've elided the host, user, and password, but the id is as written.  I'm still unsure about the JNDI lookup, but that's obviously a separate problem.

Here's my JNDI lookup reference in my Spring context:

```
    <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:global/foo/bar" id="sus2ds"/>
```

And here is more of the Tomcat console output:

```
    INFO: Configuring Service(id=global/foo/bar, type=Resource, provider-id=Default JDBC Database)
...
INFO: Creating Resource(id=global/foo/bar)
Aug 03, 2016 11:08:27 AM org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool checkPoolConfiguration
WARNING: initialSize is larger than maxActive, setting initialSize to: 5
Aug 03, 2016 11:08:27 AM org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool init
SEVERE: Unable to create initial connections of pool.
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException: [main] NoWait: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection, none available[5 in use].
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:679)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:468)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:143)
    at org.apache.tomee.jdbc.TomEEDataSourceCreator$TomEEConnectionPool.<init>(TomEEDataSourceCreator.java:221)
...

Aug 03, 2016 11:08:27 AM org.apache.tomee.jdbc.TomEEDataSourceCreator$TomEEDataSource <init>
SEVERE: Can't create DataSource
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException: [main] NoWait: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection, none available[5 in use].
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:679)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:468)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:143)
    at org.apache.tomee.jdbc.TomEEDataSourceCreator$TomEEConnectionPool.<init>(TomEEDataSourceCreator.java:221)
...

...
2016-08-03 11:08:30,080 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1] support.AbstractApplicationContext (AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sus2ds': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name "foo/bar" not found.
2016-08-03 11:08:30,084 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] context.ContextLoader (ContextLoader.java:351) - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sus2ds': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name "foo/bar" not found.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
...
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name "foo/bar" not found.
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.IvmContext.federate(IvmContext.java:199)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.IvmContext.lookup(IvmContext.java:151)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.IvmContext.lookup(IvmContext.java:291)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:828)
...
Aug 03, 2016 11:08:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sus2ds': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name "foo/bar" not found.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
...
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name "foo/bar" not found.
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.IvmContext.federate(IvmContext.java:199)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.IvmContext.lookup(IvmContext.java:151)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.IvmContext.lookup(IvmContext.java:291)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:828)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start the server and use an MBean explorer, or the JNDI explorer webapp, to take a look at the JNDI tree and get the correct name. My suspicion is you do not need `id="global/foo/bar"` but `id="foo/bar"` and keep the lookup the same in your Spring code.